# Нужна ли запятая перед "вне зависимости"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении?
Эта куртка позволит девушке выглядеть привлекательно(,) вне зависимости от погодных условий.

Answer (score 0):

В справочниках обособление условных оборотов является факультативным(что бы это слово ни значило). Я бы руководствовался примерно следующим: Зависит он манеры произношения. Пауза перед условным оборотом «вне зависимости от погодных условий» сделает его второстепенным для смысла, и запятая будет ставится; произнося же без паузы, оборот будет иметь первостепенное значение для смысла, и запятая не будет ставится.